# Add polyline to google maps with different colors android

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I'm trying to get coordinates from Firebase to create polyline on Google maps with different colors to each user. The problem is when I get this data and insert it on google maps it shows with the same color.

```
List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
colors.add(-9784993);
colors.add(-6501807);

for (int a = 0; a <= userList.size()-1; i++) {

     for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

          dataClass d = objSnapshot.getValue(dataClass.class);

          LatLng start = new LatLng(d.getLat(), d.getLongi());

          elasticList.add(start);

          polylineOptionsTest[a] = new PolylineOptions()
               .addAll(elasticList)
               .color(colors.get(a)) //Get color from list called "colors"
               .clickable(true);
          polyline2 = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptionsTest[a]);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Probably that is because `userList.size()` is equals `1` and `colors.get(a)` always returns  `colors[0]` (`-9784993`) color. In other words you add polylines for single user.</s>

Update: mistake is in `for` loop - you should use:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= userList.size()-1; a++) {
```

instead of

```
for (int a = 0; a <= userList.size()-1; i++) {
```

you increase `i` variable, not `a`.

Comment: userList.size() is bigger then 1